# XLSXWriter write arrays variables to excel

Tags: php, arrays, excel, variables

How can i write variables from arrays to excel.
The array is looking like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => color
    [1] => size
)
```

XLSXWriter is only writing the last array to the file.

```
$header = [ '1' => 'string', 
            '2' => 'string',
            '3' => 'string',
            '4' => 'string' ];

$writer = new XLSXWriter();
$writer->setAuthor('AUTHOR'); 
$writer->writeSheet($exceldata, 'SHEET1', $header); 
$writer->writeToFile("/mnt/excel/" . "file.xlsx"  );
```

Comment: _A small Aside_ Are you really writing to the `\mnt` directory, see http://www.linfo.org/mnt.html

Comment: Its not clear where the `The array is looking like this:` came from? lts not the PHP code you show us

Comment: array is from file_get_contents($url);

Comment: $url = 'https://';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json_obj = json_decode($data, true);
  
 foreach ($json_obj['items'] as $order) {
 
 
 
 }
$value1 =  $order['1'];
$value2= $order['size']['2'];
$value3= $order['3'];



$exceldata = array ($value1, $value2, $value3);
 }

Comment: Probably would be better to add that to your question, using the EDIT link

Answer (score 0):

Use array with data and write it in your file.

```
$header = [ '1' => 'string', 
            '2' => 'string',
            '3' => 'string',
            '4' => 'string' ];

// This is array with data
// $data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = array(
    array('0','color'),
    array('0','3','4'),
    array('color', 'size')
);

$writer = new XLSXWriter();
$writer->writeSheetHeader('Sheet1', $header );

// Let's write the data
foreach($data as $row) {
    $writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1', $row );
}

$writer->writeToFile("/mnt/excel/" . "file.xlsx");
```

Comment: This was almost what i needed! the file_get_contents content could get a lot of  objects who i filter by the 4 header. One array should contain the data for the 4 headers